# How do I find a string in another string, and then replace the string with string.empty without using any c# methods?

Tags: c#

```
            string input = "banana";
            string pattern = "an";
            string output = "";
            string midput = "";           


        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < pattern.Length; j++)
            {
                midput += input[i];

                if (midput.Length == pattern.Length)
                {
                    if (midput[i] != pattern[j])
                    {
                        output += midput[i];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        i += pattern.Length - 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(output);
```

I have used this algorithm who's goal is to find a pattern in a string and replace it with string.empty. The pattern can be any number number of characters but must not exceed the length of the string. My algorithm does not completely work so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve without any methods?

Comment: For example user types in" Banana" and types in pattern "ana"; output should be "Bna".

Comment: I mean why you don't want use [String.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netcore-3.1)?

Comment: `Our stupid teacher doesn't want us using replace(), substring(), split(), IndexOf()` that's the purpose I would assume. How would you understand how the underlying code works then?

Comment: Oh, and btw, this can be done using a single loop and a string builder.

Comment: The assignment was for one character pattern which I figured out but i'm trying to get a bonus by trying to solve it for more than 1 character input. Besides I'm in grade 12 this is a uni assignment.

Comment: Why not just walk through the string, and at each character see if the pattern starts there. If it does, increment `i` by the pattern length - 1 and continue the loop. If it doesn't, append that character to the output.

Comment: Enter a word
banana
Enter a pattern. Pattern must not exceed in character size of word
an
bbn

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < pattern.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (input[i] != pattern[j])
                    {
                        output += input[i];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        i += pattern.Length - 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        Console.WriteLine(output)

Comment: Don't change the value of a `for` loop variable inside the loop. Don't put code in the comments if your posted the question, just edit your question. What do you not understand about your code / algorithm? Are you familiar with state machines?

Comment: Given the input "Banana" and the pattern "na". Should the method return "Bana" or "Ba" ?

Comment: It should return Ba

Comment: Your new code has a problem with `midput`.

Comment: It's always interesting to see where questions go.  I posted a solution in the comments in the authors [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64165238/2330053) literally HOURS ago.  Not surprisingly, the solutions here are pretty similar.  [Here's that solution over at Repl.it](https://repl.it/@IdleMind/SOStringRemovePatternLowLevel#main.cs)....

Comment: Yes ! this solution also works but I already used someone else's solution and have submitted. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like walk through the string one character at a time (as you are doing), and at each character see if the pattern starts there (as you are also doing). But I would set a `bool` to track if the pattern was found or not, and then if it was, increment `i` by the pattern length - `1` and continue the loop. If it wasn't, then append that character to the output.

```
public static string RemovePattern(string input, string pattern)
{
    string output = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        // If there aren't enough characters left in the string
        // then we don't need to check for the pattern
        if (i + pattern.Length > input.Length)
        {
            output += input[i];
        }
        else
        {
            // Assume we will find the pattern
            bool foundPattern = true;

            for (int j = 0; j < pattern.Length; j++)
            {
                if (input[i + j] != pattern[j])
                {
                    // If a character wasn't a match for the pattern, 
                    // set our bool and break out of the loop
                    foundPattern = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // If we found the pattern, increment 'i' so we skip it. 
            // Otherwise add the character to our output
            if (foundPattern)
            {
                i += pattern.Length - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                output += input[i];
            }
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Exactly Thank you. A lot of people told me to implement a boolean but I was very confused on how to implement it. I knew I needed a pattern.length + i > input.length statement because I tried a input: anish, ani | and the output would be sh, but it didn't work because of that.  The only problem was I made it pattern.length => input.length + i and that didn't work so I gave up. Thanks again :)

Comment: It's a little sketchy to modify the loop variable inside the loop, but it's one way to do it.

Comment: Yeah now I'm going to figure out part 3 which is basically replacing the found pattern in the string with a user entered 'replacer' instead of string.empty. This entire assignment in general was really easy if we could use the prebuilt methods.

Comment: Yeah, I hear you. But this is really a good way to learn to think in loops and iterations. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Using a `while` loop you can process each `input` position testing for the `pattern`, and copying the character if `pattern` isn't present (or there is no longer room for a match):

```
var sbOut = new StringBuilder();
var inputPos = 0;

while (inputPos < input.Length) {
    var atPattern = false;
    if (input.Length - inputPos >= pattern.Length) { // room for pattern?
        var patternPos = 0;
        for (; patternPos < pattern.Length; ++patternPos) {
            if (input[inputPos + patternPos] != pattern[patternPos])
                break;
        }
        atPattern = patternPos == pattern.Length; // did we match entire pattern?
    }

    if (atPattern)
        inputPos += pattern.Length; // skip over pattern
    else
        sbOut.Append(input[inputPos++]); // copy input to output
}
var output = sbOut.ToString();
```

Note that the .Net Core implementation creates a list of match pattern locations and then copies each chunk that is outside the matches.

Comment: This solution also works but I can't use ToString(), so I used Rufus's solution, but thanks for your help. :)

Comment: @AnishAhuja Well, proper C# programming when building strings is to use `StringBuilder` and `ToString`. Perhaps you should discuss that with your teacher :) But you could just use `String.+` to build the string instead.